# Determine ASCII value of a row/column in a 2D array of characters

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array

Trying to figure out how to go about calculating the total value of ASCII characters in a row of a 2D array. From what I understand I must create a for-loop to loop through each instance within the array but I am unsure of how to go about doing it. Another solution that was given to me was to use a HashSet, but I am wary of using one because I have no experience with them. A test experiment I've tried was going through were going through each character of the array and adding them all up, not very efficient, of course.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class SmartPuzzleProgram{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    char[][] table = new char[5][5];
    table[0][0] = 'S';
    table[0][1] = 'M';
    table[0][2] = 'A';
    table[0][3] = 'R';
    table[0][4] = 'T';
    table[1][1] = 'T';
    table[1][2] = 'S';
    table[1][3] = 'M';
    table[2][2] = 'R';
    table[2][4] = 'S';
    table[3][1] = 'S';
    table[3][2] = 'M';
    table[4][2] = 'T';
    table[4][3] = 'S';

    int rows = 5;
    int columns = 5;    

    for(int k = 0; k>=0; k++){

      System.out.println("   | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |");
      System.out.println("---+---+---+---+---+---+");
      System.out.println(" 1 | "+table[0][0]+" | "+table[0][1]+" | "+table[0][2]+" |   "+table[0][3]+" | "+table[0][4]+" |");
      System.out.println("---+---+---+---+---+---+");
      System.out.println(" 2 | "+table[1][0]+" | "+table[1][1]+" | "+table[1][2]+" | "+table[1][3]+" | "+table[1][4]+" |");
      System.out.println("---+---+---+---+---+---+");
      System.out.println(" 3 | "+table[2][0]+" | "+table[2][1]+" | "+table[2][2]+" | "+table[2][3]+" | "+table[2][4]+" |");
      System.out.println("---+---+---+---+---+---+");
      System.out.println(" 4 | "+table[3][0]+" | "+table[3][1]+" | "+table[3][2]+" | "+table[3][3]+" | "+table[3][4]+" |");
      System.out.println("---+---+---+---+---+---+");
      System.out.println(" 5 | "+table[4][0]+" | "+table[4][1]+" | "+table[4][2]+" | "+table[4][3]+" | "+table[4][4]+" |");
      System.out.println("---+---+---+---+---+---+");

      System.out.println("Enter a row (1-5): ");
      Scanner scRow = new Scanner(System.in);
      int m = scRow.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Enter a column (1-5): ");
      Scanner scCol = new Scanner(System.in);
      int n = scCol.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Enter a letter (S, M, A, R or T): ");
      Scanner scChar = new Scanner(System.in);
      char c = scChar.next().charAt(0);

      if (m < 1 || m > 5){
        System.out.println("Invalid: Enter a valid row. ");
      }
      else if (n < 1 || n > 5){
        System.out.println("Invalid: Enter a valid column. ");
      }
      else if (c != 'S' && c != 'M' && c != 'A' && c != 'R' && c != 'T'){
        System.out.println("Invalid: Enter a valid character. ");
      }
      else{
        table[(m-1)][(n-1)] = c;
      }
     //if ((int)table[0][] == 391 && (int)table[1][] == 391 && (int)table[2][] == 391 && (int)table[3][] == 391 && (int)table[4][] == 391 
     //   && (int)table[][0] == 391 && (int)table[][1] == 391 && (int)table[][2] == 391 && (int)table[][3] == 391 && (int)table[][4] == 391){
     //  System.out.println("Congrats! You win!");
     //}
    }
  }
}
```

What is supposed to happen is that once the user has gotten S M A R and T in a 5-character line covering the entire 5x5 array is that the game declares the user a winner. This can be calculated through the addition of ASCII values which end up equaling 391 in any direction. If anyone has a solution with preferably a for-loop, it would be great.

Comment: You need a nested for-loop.

Comment: You may be able to use one scanner instead of three.

Comment: What happens if the line contains S M A S S?

Comment: It would have to line up in columns as well, so I think it should be fine. It's just a basic game.

Comment: What if the line is `TRAMS`?

Comment: Perfectly fine, the order does not matter, simply the value

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to look at the line they just entered their letter on, then try this:

```
int total = 0;
for (int column = 0; column < 5; column++)
{
    total += table[m-1][column];
}

if (total == 391)
{
    // you won!
}
```

If, by "equaling 391 in any direction", you mean that the letters can appear in columns or diagonals as well, then you'll need to loop through those as well.  Can you clarify if this is what you meant?

Also, S,M,A,R,T won't be the only set of five letters that will add up to 391, but you're filtering the input on just those five letters, so you should be ok.

To include all rows, thereby including the preset values:

```
for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
{
    int total = 0;  // reset the total on each row

    // total the cells on the current row
    for (int column = 0; column < 5; column++)
    {
        total += table[row][column];
    }

    if (total == 391)
    {
        // you won!
        break;  // no need to continue calculating the rest of the rows
    }
}
```

To check by column, just swap the 'for' loops around:

```
for (int column = 0; column < 5; column++)
{
    int total = 0;  // reset the total on each row

    // total the cells on the current column
    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
    {
        total += table[row][column];
    }

    if (total == 391)
    {
        // you won!
        break;  // no need to continue calculating the rest of the rows
    }
}
```

To check the diagonals:

```
int total = 0;

// total the cells on the current row
for (int rowcolumn = 0; rowcolumn < 5; rowcolumn++)
{
    total += table[rowcolumn][rowcolumn];  // notice that the both indices are identical
}

if (total == 391)
{
    // you won!
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, it needs to include the preset values as well